# How to create private RealmObjects in a shared Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

My goal is pretty simple: I need to create private `RealmObjects` in a shared `Realm`.

I already created objects and stored them in a shared `realm`. I would like to give users the ability to store their objects privately though. As far as I know I have two ways to accomplish this, but none of them is working.

SOLUTION 1: using permissions to let `Users` share Realm objects to each other like in the following sample:

```
public static void setActiveUser(final SyncUser user) {
        if (user.isValid()) {
            SyncConfiguration defaultConfig = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, Colombo.SERVER_URL).build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(defaultConfig);
            Realm realm = user.getManagementRealm();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    String includeAll = "*";
                        change = new PermissionChange(includeAll, includeAll, true, true, false);
                        realm.insert(change);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the synchronized `Realms` are visibile just to the current `SyncUser`.

SOLUTION 2: Create a "common" `SyncUser` to save/show public items and a private `SyncUser` for each registered user to collect his private items, switching from common to private `SyncUser` depending on the needs. Anyway it seems quite inefficient to me. How does it sound to you? Do you think there's another way I can do it?

Comment: `I need to create private RealmObjects in a shared Realm`

What do you mean by private? private as in no other users should access them, or private as in, only matters/specific to this user? 

For the latter, you can add a UUID to the "private" object, so you can query on them per user, if you don't want the object to be visible at all, you need to create a separate Realm per user, because you can't share partially the schema.

Comment: For private I mean a Realm Object stored on the server but accessible just to the creator user.
Using UUID isn't safe because other users will be able to access to objects for which they haven't permission (e.g. querying server by replacing their own UUID with one of another user)

Comment: The permission API applies to the entire Realm, so if you need some objects to be private, then I'm afraid you need to separate them in their own Realm, by using an endpoint that is user dependent (ex: `http://server/~/Private` each user will only see his Realm `Private`. This way you'll end up with two Realms, once `Shared` and one `Private`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Realm's authentication mechanism to provide different login permissions to different accounts for a single Realm.

As Nabil said, you can programmatically control access by assigning UUIDs to users, and then querying only for them per user.